# How to apply SVG filter to an element?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I want to apply the following filter to some link element in my html page:
My web page running on Chrome.
(I found that filter somewhere on the net)

```
<filter id="tf" filterRes="172"> 
    <feImage xlink:href="noise.jpg"> 
    <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic" k1="1"> 
    <feMorphology operator="erode" radius="30"> 
</filter>
```

- I got the noise.jpg as a file in the root folder (where my index.html is)
- The css is embedded in the html.index by the `style` element

In what file extension the filter should be saved?

How can I refer to that file in the css code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the filter in a SVG document (you can also embed it in your XHTML document), then you can simply refer to it in your CSS filter property by its URL, like this: `filter: url(myfilter.svg#filterID)`.

On WebKit however it works only if the SVG filter is embedded in the document.